# Using a different css file if resolution is below 1920 x 1080p

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that if the resolution is below 1920x1080 a scrollbar appears and in my opinion isn't the look I was going for. I want it all to fit on one page, so how can I change the css file to a different one if the resolution is under 1080p where I can adjust the content to be smaller so that it will fit lower resolutions?

Answer (score 4):

Media queries to the rescue!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

Comment: @ gman: The above answers what you actually asked, but you'd probably be better off using just one CSS file with a media query *inside* it, which has the advantage of working well on devices where the dimensions change (e.g., portrait vs. landscape). If you use separate *files* for that, then the device has to download the other one when the query becomes true. From your question, it sounds like you just want to change one or two rules, not the whole stylesheet.

Comment: I concur with @T.J.Crowder, there is the option of putting it all in the same file. However, the two separate downloads probably won't have a significant impact on page speed, and combining the queries forces all users to download all styles (instead of just the smaller screens). Both approaches are valid; read the article, consider both opinions, and decide which works for you.

Comment: I can't say that I completely understand it. I added in my <head>  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="home1.css" /> and put this in home1.css to see if it changed at 900p. It didn't change. What am I doing wrong? Also this is more of a desktop version so orientation changing isn't important                                              .logoPaper{
 height:500px;
 }

Comment: Well max-width: 800px indicates that it is only included at 800px or less. You can also do min-width, max-height, min-height, etc. You'll have to adjust the numbers to what you want. Read the article, it has all the information you need.

Comment: I've read the article and I made changes based on dpi, but still it doesn't work. <link rel="stylesheet" "@media print and (max-resolution: 3291dpi)" href="home1.css" />       .logoPaper{ height:500px; }

Comment: 3291dpi? That's... very high.